# can regex be used to index/slice parts of string?

Tags: regex

So I have a list of serial numbers in the following format:

Serial Number: `CN073GTT74445714892L`

I was wondering if regex can be used to extract just the last 6 chars?

So in this case, it is `14892L`

forget to mention, there is other unrelated text in the document, so how would i make so the match pattern is always after "serial Number: " ?

EDIT - this worked  (?<=\s.{29}).{6}$

Comment: What language do you use? What have you tried?

Comment: Your question title is a lot broader than your actual question. The short answer is: yes. Read the documentation on regex expressions and it should be pretty clear.

Comment: Hi mrzasa, the tool is a dashboard like "ticketing system" we use at work. there is a pluggin that allows us to use regex syntax to "search" for things, it seems to be the same syntax that works here -https://regexr.com/

Comment: Is serial number is in predefined or fixed for i mean it should start with this end with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a regex:

```
.{6}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OsN8bL/1/)

But you can do it without it, and it's an advisable solution. E.g. in Ruby:

```
"CN073GTT74445714892L"[-6..-1]
```

in Python:

```
In [4]: "CN073GTT74445714892L"[-6:]
Out[4]: '14892L'
```

Comment: Awesome this is definitely matching the last six :-)  However i forget to mention, there is other unrelated text in the document, so how would i make so the patters is always after "serial Number: " ?

Comment: What is the pattern for a serial number? Is `L` always the last letter? What are other parts of the text?

Answer (score 1):

**Regex is ideally used to identify patterns. If it's only the last 6 digits you're interested in, then a normal string manipulation will work too.**

e.g in Python, you could use:

```
str = "CN073GTT74445714892L"
str[-6:]
```